# condition for loop c++ odd behavior

Tags: c++, for-loop, scope

I have a problem concerning the scope of variables inside for loops in c++.
I have a variable j that counts a certain condition as seen in the code below

```
int j;
for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
    if ((betaSol(i,0) >= -HalfPi) && (betaSol(i,0) <= HalfPi)){
        // j gives size of new vector where beta is within bounds
        j++;
    }
}
Eigen::MatrixXd vectorname(j,1);
```

Now I want to use the same j in the condition of the next for loop as follows

```
 for (int ii = 0; ii<j; ii++ ){
        vectorname(ii,0)  =  functionname(alphaSol_filt(ii,0),betaSol_filt(ii,0));
    }
```

Here is where the problem occurs. 
This becomes an infinite loop and ii goes out of bounds. The strange thing is that when I replace the second loop with the following:

```
  for (int ii = 0; ii<j; ii++ ){
    std::cout << j <<std::endl;
  }
```

it does work correctly. However if I change anything, then it becomes an infinite loop and I do not know what happens

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  You've not initialized `j`, so you get indeterminate values to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am using the same j value that I have initialized in the 1st line. Also if I output the value of j outside the first for loop, I get the correct value.

Comment: `int j;` does not initialize `j`. `int j = 0;` does.

Comment: Could you show us the functions `alphaSol_filt` and `betaSol_filt`?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an empty initialization, j is initialized to whatever value happens to be in the memory space it is stored in, at least with most compilers I've used.  Since you increment j I assume you don't initialize it in the loop, so you'll probably need to put j = 0, or some other value that makes sense for your program.

As for the second loop always looping, I have seen compilers set initialized ints with no value assigned to the maximum possible value for ints (2,147,483,647), which would take a very long time to loop through even with not much being done and would seem like an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

use :

`int j=0;`

instead of

`int j;`

and check if the functions within the `for` loop change the value of `ii` or `j` that makes the loop infinite.